# Different Deletion from seemingly equivalent motions

Tags: cursor-motions

I have been learning vim for some time now and I am loving it but there is something that confuses me a little bit.

For discussion proposes lets say that we have the following text
`foo.bar`
with the cursor over the f. If I press `w` the cursor then moves to the dot `.`. Alternatively if I press `f.` the cursor moves to the dot as well. So it seems that both movements are equivalent in this case, so I would expect that if I use `d {motion}` the result should be the same with either motion, but in the first case the result is

`.bar`

and in the second is

`bar`

so they are not really equivalent. This breaks my initial impression that we can think modularly about the commands, like thinking independently about actions and motions.

I apologize if this is too basic.

Comment: See `:h exclusive`

Comment: @Matt Thank you, that answers my question. I guess I didn't understand motions as well as I should.